# MySQL get MAX of a varchar like "500x400"

Tags: mysql, sql, max, varchar

Is there any chance to get in MySQL the `MAX` of a column containing varchar like "500x400" or "800x600". They are sizes of frames.

I would need the max of the multiplication of the 2 numbers. 500x400 => 200 000.

The `my_frame_size` table is like

```
+--------------------+
  Id      frame_size
+--------------------+
  1        500x400
  2        800x600
  3        400x300
  4        600x400
  5        1000x700
```

Comment: Consider normalising your schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily take take the max . . . but it is not what you want.  Instead, calculate the area:

```
select t.*,
       substring_index(frame_size, 'x', 1) * substring_index(frame_size, 'x', -1) as area
from t;
```

You can `order by` the area or use `max()` on the calculation to get the maximum size.